# Web Dev Helper like HTTP request trace in IE8

Tags: http, request, trace

The awesome tool Web Development Helper allows me to see ALL the http requests from the browser (IE6/IE7) to the server. However the tool does not seem to work in IE8-RC1.

1. Does IE8 developer tools have a similar feature built in?
2. If yes, how do I access it?

TIA
rams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preference is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/), it works with all browsers I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought IE8 developer tools had the request trace feature built in. I agree Fiddler is more powerful but for quick tests an integrated tool is handy

Comment: IE8 developer tools is pretty much the same tool that you can download for IE7.  Its not Firebug, it just does one job (DOM/CSS inspection) not 3.  Fiddler is made available on the IE tool bar, I'm not sure how it could be made any quicker and its certainly way more informative than anything else.

Comment: Fiddler is very useful. Completely agree. However it seems to track ALL http requests from my machine. I would need to setup filters to eliminate requests that I am not interested in. This is what I meant by Fiddler not being quick. But it sure does solve my problem.

Comment: True, it does pickup too much if have a lot else going on.  Typcially turning on filters, selection only IE traffic and filter RSS does the job.  Its quick enough for me not to desire yet another in-browser tool. Even on Firefox I prefer fiddler over the plug-in offerings.